# Why is "plugins_loaded" not called/fired?

Tags: plugins, textdomain

I am trying call `load_plugin_textdomain` once the plugins are loaded, however this does not happen. I do have a plugin activated, so shouldn't this fire?

```
add_action("plugins_loaded", "test_override");

function init_localization()
{
    echo "init_localization<br>";
    load_plugin_textdomain
    (
        TEXT_DOMAIN, 
        false, 
        LANGUAGE_DIR
    );
}

function test_override()
{
    echo "text_override<br>";
}
```

In another context, when calling `add_action("init", "init_custom_post_types")`, it works fine.

It may be of interest to know that I am working on a custom theme.

Thanks if you can provide any guidance, or ask if you need to know anything that could help you help me.

Comment: In additional to what Geert mentioned, why are you not using load_theme_textdomain() instead if you're working on a theme.

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at the [wp-settings.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-settings.php) file. You’ll see that the `plugins_loaded` action is triggered before the theme is loaded. The first action available for themes to hook into is the `after_setup_theme` action.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for the guidance Geert and splashingpixels. I wasn't using those events or functions simply because I did not know of them and relied on another project. Now I do get that the action is called, however the translations are not applied. The translation items are for custom post type labels. Where should I look to have them picked up from the PO/MO?

Comment: Many plugins don’t hook their translations to the proper hook (like `after_setup_theme` or `init`). In that case you can’t override them from within your theme. Here’s [how plugins should load translations properly](http://geertdedeckere.be/article/loading-wordpress-language-files-the-right-way). If the plugin author doesn’t update the code you could still go for a [must-use-plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) workaround.

Comment: Guess I wasn't clear. splashingpixels aligned me onto the right path: I'm actually building a custom theme, so I don't need info on plugins. I'm using `add_action("after_setup_theme", "init_localization")`, but the admin/CMS part of WP does not apply the strings from the PO/MO to the elements as expected. Any tips?